# Encode H.264 to TS

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg2-ts

I want to encode H.264 bit stream to TS(using .264 file as input). 
I added a PAT, PMT and formed PES Packets.
When I run **ffmpeg.exe video_31-05-17-05_49PM.ts**, it says **no stream found**.

```
    Output #0, mpegts, to 'video_31-05-17-05_49PM.ts':
    Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

But , if I run **ffmpeg -i video_31-05-17-05_49PM.ts**, it gives the following error:

```
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 3 0
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 10 1
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 5 2
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 3
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 11 4
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 7 5
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 12 6
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 13 7
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 7 8
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 9 9
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] Invalid mb type in I-frame at 6 10
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 5 11
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 5 12
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 6 13
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 4 14
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 4 15
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] mb incr damaged
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 4 17
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 3 18
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 6 19
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 11 20
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 11 21
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 15 22
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 6 23
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 12 24
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 25
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 26
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 12 27
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 14 28
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 29
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 10 30
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 10 31
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 10 32
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 16 33
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 34
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 8 35
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 13 36
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 16 37
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 10 38
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 17 39
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] ac-tex damaged at 11 40
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 19 41
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 12 42
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 13 43
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] skipped MB in I-frame at 19 44
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] Warning MVs not available
    [mpeg2video @ 000000000044e800] concealing 3600 DC, 3600 AC, 3600 MV errors in I frame
    Input #0, mpegts, from 'video_31-05-17-05_49PM.ts':
      Duration: 00:00:00.10, start: 0.020000, bitrate: 509163 kb/s
      Program 1
      No Program
        Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    At least one output file must be specified
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong going on?

Comment: From 264 to TS should be `ffmpeg -i in.264 -c copy out.ts`

Comment: @Mulvya, thanks for your help. but I want to do it manually, without ffmpeg or etc.

Comment: @sourav, were you able to convert h.254 to ts? I'm also interested.